# Save my image as .TIFF

Tags: image, matlab, tiff

I have an image (medical image) stocked as .TIFF file, when I read it I’ve found 4 matrix the first, the second and the third one are the RGB components of my image the fourth one is a binary matrix (contains only 1 values), I dont know what is it.  I’ve denoised it but the problem is :
-when I save it I got 000 values (black image) but when I open it under matlab I see that it is not an empty matrix this is my code :

```
t = Tiff([source2,'',num2str(v)],'w');
tagstruct.ImageLength     = 1000;
tagstruct.ImageWidth      = 1024;
tagstruct.Photometric     = Tiff.Photometric.RGB;
tagstruct.BitsPerSample   = 32;
tagstruct.SamplesPerPixel = 4;
tagstruct.RowsPerStrip    = 1000;
tagstruct.ExtraSamples    =Tiff.ExtraSamples.AssociatedAlpha;
tagstruct.PlanarConfiguration = Tiff.PlanarConfiguration.Chunky;
tagstruct.Software        = 'MATLAB';
tagstruct.SampleFormat=Tiff.SampleFormat.IEEEFP;
t.setTag(tagstruct);
t.write(single(Iy_d));
t.close();
```

I want to read the head of the file in order to check my BitsPerSample but I couldn’t

```
Xn= imread([source,'', num2str(v)],'tif')
```

I got this error :

```
info = imfinfo(Xn);
Error using imfinfo (line 80)
Expected FILENAME to be one of these types:

char

Instead its type was uint8
```

this make me confused because it shouldn't be uint8 !, So I convert it to double

```
Xn=im2double(imread([source,'', num2str(v)],'tif'))
```

But without any avail

Comment: I suspect the extra value is an alpha/transparency layer - hence the `tagstruct.ExtraSamples    =Tiff.ExtraSamples.AssociatedAlpha;`

Comment: Thank you but it is not working :/ I have tried the 3 cases 0, 1 and two since LibTiff defines these values: EXTRASAMPLE_UNSPECIFIED = 0; EXTRASAMPLE_ASSOCALPHA = 1; EXTRASAMPLE_UNASSALPHA = 2;